# Same dates for multiple data series

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, linechart

I have an array **timeSeries** with let's say 10 series of 100 data points each. I have another array **dates** with 100 dates.

How do I get d3 to plot the 10 series on the same chart, using the 100 dates as their x values and the 100 respective values (e.g. timeSeries[0]) as their y values?

*To be clear, the 10 arrays within timeSeries only have the y values - think of them as price series. Those 10 arrays (with 100 prices each) map exactly to the 100 dates in dates which I need to get into this somehow. If there was only one price series, I'd parse them into one array and do d.date and d.price, but it's probably not efficient to have 10 (or 1000) of those?*

This gets me halfway there:

```
canvas.selectAll("path")
    .data(timeSeries)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", d3.line().x((d,i) => x(i)).y(d => y(d)));
```

Now I just need to find a way to use **dates** rather than **i**...

What's the most efficient way of achieving this, without having 10 associative arrays with the dates in every single one of them? I might well scale this to 100 or 1000 so would like to keep this as lean as possible.

Thank you!

[Bonus question: Let's say I add another layer of nesting to timeSeries, i.e. have 10 series of 2D arrays - why doesn't (d => y(d[0])) plot anything even though the console output is the same as in the case above?]

Comment: Sorry, the 10 arrays within **timeSeries** only have the y values - think of them as price series. Those 10 arrays (with 100 prices each) map exactly to the 100 dates in **dates** which I need to get into this somehow.

If there was only one price series, I'd parse them into one array and do d.date and d.price, but it's probably not efficient to have 10 (or 1000) of those?

Comment: Yes. I just realised that. You can also edit your question making that point clear.

Comment: Thanks, added a little bit of an explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that...

> 10 arrays (with 100 prices each) map exactly to the 100 dates in dates [array]

... you only need the **index** of those dates.

So, this can be your line generator:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x((d, i) => xScale(dates[i]))
  //index here--------------^
```

Here is a very basic demo. I'm creating the dates array, from 2011 to 2017...

```
var dates = d3.range(2011, 2018, 1).map(d => d3.timeParse("%Y")(d));
```

... and then creating one array with 10 inner arrays, each one with 10 random values for the y axis:

```
var data = d3.range(10).map(d => d3.range(10).map(d => Math.random() * 150));
```

Here is the result:

```js
var dates = d3.range(2011, 2018, 1).map(d => d3.timeParse("%Y")(d));
var data = d3.range(10).map(d => d3.range(10).map(d => Math.random() * 150));
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, 300]).domain(d3.extent(dates));
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x((d, i) => xScale(dates[i]))
  .y(d => d);
var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```